# Unresolved attribute error not showing up in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using vs code- insiders for python. I had an `unresolved attribute` problem in my code, and vs code couldn't detect it, I found the error after running the code. Is there a way to make this error visible while coding. For example, pycharm shows the error on hovering over the attribute.
For vsc I am using `Pylance` language server and `flake8` linter. I have attached screenshots please have a look.

**vs code**:

[image]

**pycharm**:

[image]

Comment: You should be finding you attribute errors by using unit tests. Python is a dynamic language after all.

Comment: yes, i did that. But is there a way to get these while writing the code.? (like any linter changes/config edits). It would save time.

Comment: Err... but you're writing your tests as you go, surely!

Answer (score 0):

Changing linter to pylint and adding  `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--enable=F,E,W"],` in settings.json worked.